# JSON Array parsing in PHP and updating in the database

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax

Though this is a textbook problem, but I'm not able to parse from json object. I have a json object coming from a page, and I need to extract the `ID,fieldText` value so that I can update the table.

Here is how I'm capturing the json and converting it into array, not sure how to extract the values.

```
if(isset($_POST['postData'])){
 $json = json_decode($_POST['postData'],true);
foreach ($json as $key => $value) 
{

   print_r($key);
   //print_r($value);
   foreach ($value as $k => $val)   
  {
        //echo "$k | $val <br />";
   } }
```

I need to update the table with [ID] and [fieldText] :

```
Result should like this::(1:Hello World), (2:The rising Star),(3: Terminator)
```

My JSON object is like this:

```
Array(

[fieldName] => Array
    (
        [0] => fieldText[1]
        [1] => fieldText[2]
        [2] => fieldText[3]
    )

[fieldText] => Array
    (
        [0] => HelloWorld
        [1] => The rising Star
        [2] => Terminator

    )

[ID] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 2
        [2] => 3
    ))
```

Answer (score 1):

Hi it seems that there are three arrays in your JSON, I think it would be better to change the way you generate the JSON to make it simple to understand.

```
// assumes $arr as the $_POST['postData'] in your case
$arr = array("1"=>"Hello World", "2"=>"The Rising Star", "3"=>"Terminator"); 
$j = json_encode($arr);
$json = json_decode($j,true);
foreach ($json as $key => $value) 
{
echo '('.$key.','. $value.')';
}
```

The results are :

```
(1,Hello World)(2,The Rising Star)(3,Terminator)
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: thank you for your attempt. changing json is not possible,

Answer (score 1):

Hope you can do something like this.

```
$jsonData = Array(

'Name' => Array
(
    0 => 'Text1',
    1 => 'Text2',
    2 => 'Text3'
),

'Value' => Array
(
    0 => 'HelloWorld',
    1 => 'The rising Star',
    2 => 'Terminator'

),

'ID' => Array
(
    0 => 1,
    1 => 2,
    2 => 3
)
);

$length = count($jsonData['ID']);

for($j=0;$j<$length;$j++) {
    echo "(".$jsonData['ID'][$j].": ".$jsonData['Value'][$j].")<br/>";
}
```

Comment: in which line? Show me the code you are trying please.

Comment: if(isset($_POST['postData'])){
 $jsonData = json_decode($_POST['postData'],true);

 $length = count($jsonData['ID']);
 //echo "$length";

for($j=0;$j<$length;$j++) {

    echo "(".$jsonData['ID'][$j].": ".$jsonData['Value'][$j].")<br/>";
}

Comment: and getting error in echo "(".$jsonData['ID'][$j].": ".$jsonData['Value'][$j]."

Comment: you are using the exact code I'm using, I have provided you a way, because I don't know what are you getting in your postdata, you have to modify the indexes I used to your ones. I can help with that if you can print the postdata array and show it to me. Try var_dump($_POST['postData']) inside your if condition and provide the output in your question

Comment: the array that I have provided is the same one that I'm getting after printing the postdata array.

Comment: umm, first of all the JSON object you have provided is not actually a JSON object, rather a php array with few errors. I have modified the array correcting the errors and placing Indexes from my own, you can not reuse them because in your case they will be different. Secondly the var_dump result won't be like this for postdata because for a regular php array it should give something like this

Comment: array(3) { ["Name"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(5) "Text1" [1]=> string(5) "Text2" [2]=> string(5) "Text3" } ["Value"]=> array(3) { [0]=> string(10) "HelloWorld" [1]=> string(15) "The rising Star" [2]=> string(10) "Terminator" } ["ID"]=> array(3) { [0]=> int(1) [1]=> int(2) [2]=> int(3) } }

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you should make your life easier by modifying the `json` array you receive with `$_POST['data'];`. If I were in your shoes my `json` would've been exactly as you need it:

```
{ 1:'Hello World', 2:'The rising Star',3:'Terminator' }
```

But if you are not able to change it for any reason I think you could use something like this (basing this example on your code):

```
$jsonData = json_encode($_POST['json'], true);

$id = $jsonData['ID'];
$fieldText = $jsonData['fieldText'];

$arr = array();

for ($i=0; $i < count($id); $i++) { 
    $arr[(int) $id[$i]] = $fieldText[$i];
}

var_dump($arr);
```

Hope this helps you!